delay spread in the GSM channel
In GSM, we use a GMSK modulation. I would like to know what is the average delay spread for the GSM standard? Does this delay depend on the carrier frequency used?

As per 3GPP standard 100.910 (v8.20.0), the delay spread ranges from 0.5us (Rural Area) to 20us (Hilly Terrain). This is described in section C.3 of the document. These delay spread values are characterized for the typical 800MHz-2GHz frequency band used for GSM. For other carrier frequencies, it can change but it depends on the environment used for model as well (whether rural or urban etc).
